# scheduled tasks delay and device sleep

Tags: java, android, scheduler, job-scheduling, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm developing an android application, that have 3 scheduled jobs:

- Job1 uploads transactions every 1 minute
- Job2 uploads audit logs every 10 minutes
- Job3 downloads operational parameters every 2 hours

Jobs delay are not negotiable (=> no JobScheduler !)
And my client don't want jobs running when its application is not the foreground one, neither when screen is off.

I chose a simple ScheduledExecutorService to manage the jobs.
It's working pretty good, except that it seems to ignore the time when the screen was off.
For example, after a 5 hours screen off, when I wake the phone, I expect that all jobs are triggered, because they were not run since longer than their delay... But it's not. (whatever fixedRate or fixedDelay used)

So I developed a kind of watchdog, that verify every second the last jobs execution time, and add it in a ScheduledExecutorService if needed.
It's working, but I guess a better solution should exists.

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android ?

Comment: no.
Target devices don't have Google Play services installed